# undefined method `raw' for controller for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

Currently, I am upgrading my application from rails 3.2 to rails 4. When I navigate to a particular tab, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `raw' for #<LeaseController:0x00000006935e30>
```

My code:

```
        vacant.tenant = raw("Vacant")
        vacant.lease_start_date = raw("&nbsp;")
        vacant.rent_end = raw("&nbsp;")
        vacant.base_rent_monthly_amount = raw("")
        vacant.base_rent_annual_psf = raw("")
        vacant.options = raw("")
        vacant.security_deposit_amount = raw("")
        vacant.tis_amount = raw("")
        vacant.lcs_amount =raw("")
```

Why is this method now undefined?

Comment: raw is used in views not in controller...

Comment: its used in helper file

Comment: it should be in your view helper, if it is there it should not shout for controller error. May be you have placed it in the wrong place, check it please

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This helper is depreceted.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper

If you still want to use `raw` , try including

```
include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper
```

into your controller.

In rails 4 `raw` method is provided by `ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper`

You can check out its documentation at:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html

But most importantly this code belongs to view helpers, not controller.

Answer (score 4):

You can use html_safe in your controller. like this string.html_safe